# What is the difference between Ink and GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, widget, gesturedetector

When I looked at the example of `Ink` and `GestureDetector`, I found that they are providing similar effects.

Could I say that `Ink` is just a child of `GestureDetector`, which detects `onTap()` only ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Ink` does not have `onTap` but `InkWell` does.
- `Ink` is not a child of `GestureDetector` (w.r.t. OOPS).
- `InkWell` and `GestureDetector` have common attributes but they
  are different.
- GestureDetectors are roughly InkWells without ink splashes.
- InkWells are roughly GestureDetectors without fancy gesture
  detections.

In short, they are two different widgets with some common attributes.

**Further reads:** 
[Ink](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Ink-class.html) 
[InkWell](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) 
[GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

GestureDetector provides more gestures, it's a literally gesture detector.

Ink is material and provides material effects.

> A convenience widget for drawing images and other decorations on Material widgets, so that InkWell and InkResponse splashes will render over them

[Ink class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Ink-class.html)